# Reload ol.source.Cluster after moving slider

Tags: openlayers, mviewer

I try to refresh my layer with a CQL function, where the dateMin and dateMax are parameters from a slider. Because of cluster, I don't understand why the source is not refreshed. I work with openlayers 5. I've no console error with this code but it don't work :

```
var cqlFilter = 'date_debut BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000 OR date_fin BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000';
var urlTemplate = 'https://myServer/geoserver/mviewer/wfs?service=WFS&' +
'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&' +
'typeNames=mviewer:patrimoine&' +
'maxFeatures=150&' +
'CQL_FILTER=' + cqlFilter +
'&outputFormat=application/json&' +
'srsName=EPSG:4326';
var geoJSONFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var _vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  url: urlTemplate
});

function changeDate(filter) {
  var dateMin = filter[0];
  var dateMax = filter[1];
  var cqlNewFilter = 'date_debut BETWEEN '+ dateMin + ' AND ' + dateMax + ' OR date_fin BETWEEN ' + dateMin + ' AND ' + dateMax + '';
  var urlTemplate = 'https://myServer/geoserver/mviewer/wfs?service=WFS&' +
  'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&' +
  'typeNames=mviewer:patrimoine&' +
  'maxFeatures=150&' +
  'CQL_FILTER=' + cqlNewFilter +
  '&outputFormat=application/json&' +
  'srsName=EPSG:4326';
  $.ajax({
    url: urlTemplate,
  }).done(function(data) {
    _layer.getSource().clear(true);
    var features = [];
    data.features.forEach( e => {
      var feature = new ol.Feature({
        id: e.id,
        properties : e.properties,
        geometry : new ol.geom.Point(e.geometry.coordinates)
      });
      features.push(feature);
    });
    _layer.getSource().addFeatures(features);
  });

}

var _cluster = new ol.source.Cluster({
    distance: 50,
    source: _vectorSource
});
var _layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: _cluster,
  style: _patrimoineStyle
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is you view projection EPSG:4326?  If not you may be loading features to the wrong coordinates.  It would be simpler to use a url function (with urlTemplate global) and let OpenLayers handle the refresh

```
var cqlFilter = 'date_debut BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000 OR date_fin BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000';
var urlTemplate = 'https://myServer/geoserver/mviewer/wfs?service=WFS&' +
'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&' +
'typeNames=mviewer:patrimoine&' +
'maxFeatures=150&' +
'CQL_FILTER=' + cqlFilter +
'&outputFormat=application/json&' +
'srsName=EPSG:4326';
var geoJSONFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var _vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  url: function() { return urlTemplate; }
});

function changeDate(filter) {
  var dateMin = filter[0];
  var dateMax = filter[1];
  var cqlNewFilter = 'date_debut BETWEEN '+ dateMin + ' AND ' + dateMax + ' OR date_fin BETWEEN ' + dateMin + ' AND ' + dateMax + '';
  urlTemplate = 'https://myServer/geoserver/mviewer/wfs?service=WFS&' +
  'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&' +
  'typeNames=mviewer:patrimoine&' +
  'maxFeatures=150&' +
  'CQL_FILTER=' + cqlNewFilter +
  '&outputFormat=application/json&' +
  'srsName=EPSG:4326';
  _vectorSource.clear(true);
  _vectorSource.refresh();
}
```

Comment: Yes I'm in EPSG:4326. I tried your code but it doesn't work. I can load features on my map, but refresh doesn't work. http://193.48.28.84/mviewer/?config=apps/patrimoine.xml#

Comment: The data is EPSG:4326 but the view on that page is EPSG:3857 so it would need to be transformed to be viewed.  OpenLayers will do that automatically if you use the built in loader.  As you are using OpenLayers 5 you will need to clear the source before refreshing.  I combined my code with your data source and an OpenLayers example https://codepen.io/mike-000/pen/zYGRVJV and it is working, but sometimes your source returns geometry other than points which needs to be filtered out (or converted to a point) by a geometry function to avoid an error in the clustering.

Comment: ok, it's strange that my source return geometry other than points... that's why I actually obtain an error (TypeError: e is null) you think ? my error appear just when the range exclude any feature...

Comment: I had records without geometry, and since I dropped them, it work perfectly. Thanks !